# randomized smooth slope in python

Tags: python, math, coordinates

How do I create a randomized smooth slope (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iK6l.png)) using python? Create as in generate a list of coordinates, with x increasing at a constant rate. I know that questions similar to this have already been asked and answered, but I found none for python specifically.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get a completely smooth arbitrary curve in any computer language, since the language deals with finitely many pieces of data while the curve requires infinitely many. Even the graphic you show only has 1,309 pixels horizontally.

The usual way in Python to draw a graph that *looks* smooth is to create many values for the x-coordinate. A common way to do that for your graph, which looks like has x-values between -2 and 26, is

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-2.0, 26.0, num=1000)
```

Note that I used one thousand values of x. You then create the corresponding y-values. If you want a random curve, use some random parameters in your expression. Here is one example:

```
y = ((x - uniform(-2, 26)) * (x - uniform(-2, 26)) * (x - uniform(-2, 26))
    * (x - uniform(-2, 26)))
```

There are many other ways to randomly define a function--I chose one that one chooses four random x-intercepts for the curve. Let me know more details about what you want and I might be able to define another one for you.

You then plot those values in a graphics package such as matplotlib. Here is a code sample with its result. This version limits the y-values to between 0 and 10 and defines a function `randomfunc` that you can use after the graph is made to calculate the value of y for any particular x. To find the y-value at x=1, execute `randomfunc(1, x1, x2, x3, x4, ymax, ymin)`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Key values
xmin = -2.0
xmax = 26.0
scale = 10.0

def randomfunctemp(x, x1, x2, x3, x4):
    return (x-x1) * (x-x2) * (x-x3) * (x-x4)

def randomfunc(x, x1, x2, x3, x4, ymax, ymin):
    return (randomfunctemp(x, x1, x2, x3, x4) - ymin)  / (ymax - ymin) * scale

x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, num=1000)
x1, x2, x3, x4 = np.random.uniform(xmin, xmax, 4)
y = randomfunctemp(x, x1, x2, x3, x4)
ymax, ymin = y.max(), y.min()
y = randomfunc(x, x1, x2, x3, x4, ymax, ymin)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How would I randomize it, though?

Comment: What does the (-2, 26) mean? Also, How can I change the steepness of the slopes? 10,000 is too high for my needs, I need more like 10 as the max y value. @RoryDaulton

Comment: Last request, Is there a way to print out a list of the coordinates, say for every integer of x? @RoryDaulton

Comment: @TaeRugh: I edited the routine to define a function that can find the value of y for any given value of x. You also need to pass in the calculated parameters for the particular function used in the graph--I give an example. I found it simpler in this case to use numpy's random routine rather than Python's, which I used in my previous versions.